# Autocomplete in IDE during electron app development

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, autocomplete, ide, electron

I have

```
. . . 
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js"
},  
"devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.35.0"
}
```

in `package.json` of my electron app. I use Intellij Idea with installed `node.js` plugin.

`main.js`:

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
```

Intellij Idea IDE underlines `require('browser-window')` and shows warning `Module is not installed` and doesn't provide autocompletion to BrowserWindow.

Comment: `browser-window` is not a npm module. Are you just trying to do `var BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow ` ?

Comment: @FelixYadomi maybe electron classes import convention changed but autocompletion still doesn't work.